# Is "if else" treated as a single statement?

Tags: c++

Apologies if my wording is wrong.

I've been taught since high-school to add curly braces after statements such as if, while, for, etc. whenever there is more than one line of code to execute. Example:

```
while(i<12)
        i++;
        z = i+3;
        cout << "Answer is " << z << endl;
```

Will not execute what you'd expect. But the following will:

```
while(i<12){
        i++;
        z = i+3;
        cout << "Answer is " << z << endl;
}
```

However I recently came across a while loop that contains an if..else statement which seems like more than one line of code/statement when looked at, and yet it executes and works as it should regardless if it has curly braces for its scope or not.

```
while(current != NULL && !found)
          if(current->info >= newItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
            }
```

Why is that? Does it treat the if..else statement as a single statement?

Comment: Despite the poor coding practice, the code is correct.

Comment: Yes it is, otherwise it would not compile

Comment: The good habit is to *always* use braces after a `while`

Comment: Just use brackets everywhere without exception. It isn't too hard. You won't regret it.

Comment: I understand that it is poor coding practice (I always include braces) and that the code is correct, but I want to understand why it is correct? Why does it treat if..else differently than say 3 separate statements following the while loop?

Comment: Whitespace doesn't matter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if .. else is a single statement (technically it is called a [selection statement](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.select)) in C++.  Per [[stmt.select]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.select#1) the valid forms of `if` are:

> ```
> selection-statement:
>     if constexpr-opt ( init-statement-opt condition ) statement
>     if constexpr-opt ( init-statement-opt condition ) statement else statement
> ```

So

```
while(current != NULL && !found)
    if(current->info >= newItem)
        found = true;
    else
    {
        trailCurrent = current;
        current = current->link;
    }
```

is a single statement as well and behaves correctly.

Comment: Notice that it is semantically incorrect to consider the "if...else" syntax as *one statement* when the documentation you linked clearly states "`if ... statement else statement`" meaning that there are **two** statements involved. Minor nitpick, but important.

Comment: @TimKlein A *statement* is defined in part as *attribute-specifier-seq-opt selection-statement* so it is a statement.  Just because it contains statements does not means it is not one.

Comment: @NathanOliver `if … else …` is a single statement, however, technically, it's a *selection statement*, not a *compound statement*…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Fixed.  Not sure why I thought *selection statement* was listed under *compound statement*

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the clarity and references.

Comment: @user931018 No problem.  Glad to help

Comment: @TimKlein: It's definitely _one statement_. That is important to the grammar, because it means an if-statement can occur in places where only a single statement may occur. The example (after `while()`) is such a place.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for an `if` is basically:

```
if (condition) statement else statement
```

If you want to control multiple statements with either the `if` or the `else` leg, you use curly braces to group them together into a block, which is syntactically a single statement.

Likewise with `while`, `for`, and so on. Each of them controls a single statement, which can be either a simple statement or a compound statement (i.e., some number of statements grouped together into a block using curly braces).

```
while (condition) statement

do statement while (condition)

for (for-init condition ; statement) statement
```

For the moment, I'm sort of ignoring some of the more recent additions, such as defining a variable in the loop header, such as: `for (int i...)`, since that's not really relevant to the questions at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Following what you said above, am I correct in saying that if..else..if, is not a single statement? Since if..else by itself is a single statement and adding another if essentially makes it a compounding statement?

Comment: @user931018: Correct--in an `if`/the/`else if` chain, each `if` forms an independent statement (that happens to be controlled by the previous one).

Answer (score 2):

[From the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A356%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D):

```
selection-statement:
    if (expression) statement
    if (expression) statement else statement
    switch (expression) statement
```

So yes, if-else is a single statement.

Think of it this way: If if-else weren't a single statement, what else would it be? Would the `if`-part be a statement and then the `else`-part another statement? If that were the case, you should be able to use `else` as a statement on its own (without a preceding `if`), but that would make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `else` part [is part of the `if` statement](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if). This is also the reason why you can write `else if (...)`. The `if` in `else if` forms a second statement: the statement for the `else` part of the first `if`.

As others have pointed out in the comments already, relying on this can quickly lead to code that is hard to read, confusing, or even erroneous. For example:

```
if (a)
  if (b)
    ; // ...
else
  ; // this is the else for if (b), not if (a)!
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, they are single statement. You cannot write `else` without `if`. What will be if `while` loop with `if-else` loops only `if` case? Can you imagine that `else` will be executed after loop is finished?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it treat the if..else statement as a single statement?

Yes,

```
if(current->info >= newItem)
      found = true;
else
{
     trailCurrent = current;
     current = current->link;
}
```

is one statement.

The line under the `if` is one sub-statement.

The block of code under the `else` are the sub-statements.

That is true regardless of whether they are under a `while` block or not.